# The number of lines is always 0

Tags: c++, getline

Why is the number of lines always 0? It should be 10, but the output is always 0.Is anything wrong with the method?

```
int main() {
    vector<double> doubleCoefficient; // vector to store unknown number of equations (double)

    /* Read from file and assign values to vector */

    //File stream object
    ifstream inputFile;
    //Open the txt file
    inputFile.open("test.txt");

    //search for the text file
    if(!inputFile.is_open())
    {
        cerr << "Error opening file \n";
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "File found and successfully opened. \n";
    }
    double x;

    while(!inputFile.eof()){

        inputFile >> x;
        doubleCoefficient.push_back(x);
    }

    int count =0;
    string line;
    while (getline(inputFile, line)){
        count++;
    }
    cout << "Number of lines in text file:" << count << endl;

    inputFile.close();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `while(!inputFile.eof())` You go to the end of the file, so after that, You cann't read lines. 
You need to go back to the start using [fseek()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fseek/)

try

```
fseek ( inputFile , 0 , SEEK_SET );
```

before counting the lines.

Comment: it's because You start counting _from the end of the file_, so You won't count anything.